# Analysis of borrowed chords in Lush's "Single Girl"

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory, harmony, chord-progressions

I am analysing the chords from songs I like, in order to understand why I like them and to reuse the ideas in contexts that suit my voice and playing styles better.

I am going through [Lush - Single Girl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RndzuSESF8Y) now, a song in the key of A major. Verse goes like:

```
A                              D
Single girl I don't wanna be a single girl
A                              D
Single girl I don't wanna be a single girl
```

So `I` `IV`.

Then the next section is:

```
F           G        C         F
Don't wanna be on my own again tonight
F           G           D
Don't wanna put out the light
```

`F`, `G` and `C` are not diatonic in A major, but I see them as borrowed from <s>relative</s> parallel minor. Which is the best way to notate them? Am I right with:

```
bVI         bVII     bIII      bVI
Don't wanna be on my own again tonight
bVI         bVII        IV
Don't wanna put out the light
```

Or should I write it as modulating to A minor (but then again `D` would be non-diatonic)?

Comment: They're said to be borrowed from the *parallel* minor. The relative minor has the same chords basically as its relative major. There must be many more factors than the chord structure that means you like a song, I hope!

Answer (score 7):

I hear a brief resolution to tonic on "own again." As such, I would personally want a way to show that with my analysis.

You're right that F, G, and C are diatonic in A minor (the *parallel* minor, not relative; parallel keys share the same tonic, relative keys share the same key signature). But these chords are also diatonic in C major; they're I, IV, and V! In fact, this is where I hear that brief resolution, so I think it's best to hear that section as:

```
  I  IV  V  IV  V
|_________________|
       ♭III
```

We call this an *extended tonicization*. Instead of a single V/V resolving, we have a few chords in the temporary key.

This way we can easily see the cadential progression in C, which is ♭III in the overall key of A major. In other words, it's a brief phrase in the relative key of the parallel key!

You'll end up returning to A with the D chord. In fact, you may even want to approach this from a standpoint of "[text painting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_painting)"; I can't help but notice that our return to A begins on the word "light," and the reintroduction of that F♯ sure sounds bright.

Answer (score 7):

Listening to the tune, it *sounds* like a modulation to a new key, so I would avoid thinking about borrowed chords here. Since the new key doesn't sound minor and includes no minor chords it seems like C Major would be a better choice for the name of the new key.

Try to focus on what you need to know when you attempt a Roman numeral analysis. When keys modulate, I would simply notate the relevant keys:

```
    A: I  IV    I  IV C: IV V     I  IV    IV V  A: IV
    |  A  D  |  A  D  |  F  G  |  C  F  |  F  G  |  D  D  |
```

Looking at things this way makes sense (to me at least) because the chords in the second section seem to want to land on **C** (with the **IV - V**s); this is frustrated by the final chromatic **D** that leads back to the original key.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a key centre for the second section C major could be useful.  Don't worry too much about how to label C major in relation to A Major.  They weren't thinking about 'modal interchanges' or any such 'theory'.  There's not much functional harmony going on here.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard's answer provides the essential explanation this is an *extended tonicization*, but I want to add an additional point.

Borrowed chords can also involve a *chromatic mediant* relationship.

For example, the chord `F` major can be seen as a borrowed `bVI` in the key `A` major. It's also the case that the tonic `A` major chord and `F` major are *chromatic mediants*.

We can also see a chromatic mediant relationship in the to tonic regionss `A` major and `C` major.

Finally, when the second part centered around `C` repeats, the `D` goes to `F` another chromatic mediant pair.

In examples like this - where the chords don't *function* as borrowed chord - I think the chromatic mediant is simply a *desired, colorful sound*. In this song we hear that unique sound at the connections between the two parts in `A` and `C`.