# Chord exceptions in City of New Orleans

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, roman-numerals

Here are the first few chords of "City of New Orleans" as performed by Arlo Guthrie:

`F# C# F# D#m B F#`

`F# C# F# D#m B F#`

`D#m A#m C# G#`

If I lay out the chords in a roman numeral chart, starting at F#, I get:

```
| I  | ii  | iii | IV | V  | vi  | vii⁰ |
|----+-----+-----+----+----+-----+------|
| F# | G#m | A#m | B  | C# | D#m | Fdim |
```

So, in the song, he plays a `G#`. However, the chart predicts a `G#m`, which is an exception to the chart that sounds good.

Where can I read about these "exceptions"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The chords you've listed in your table are what we call the **diatonic triads** of a key. "Diatonic" basically just means "within the key," so the diatonic triads are what are created when we only use the pitches in a key's key signature.

(Quick note related to key signatures: your `vii°` chord will actually be `E♯°`, not `F°`, because E♯ is the seventh scale degree in F♯ major. For more on this concept, see [Why do notes have multiple names?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23976/why-do-notes-have-multiple-names))

The opposite of diatonic is **chromatic**. Put another way, a chromatic pitch is a pitch that is not in the key's key signature. The G♯-major chord in question has B♯ as its chordal third, which is not in the key signature of F♯ (that would be B♮).

So whenever we have a chromatic chord like this, we want to try and understand how it functions. *In many cases, the appearance of an unexpected major triad can be understood as being a temporary V (or "dominant") of another chord.* In this case, the G♯-major chord can best be understood as a temporary V of the C♯ that comes before it. We say that this G♯-major chord is V/V (read "five of five") because it is V of C♯, which is itself V of the tonic F♯. We also call this chord a *secondary dominant* or *applied dominant*.

Typically the secondary dominant chord appears *before* its resolution; in other words, it's more normal for the G♯-major chord to resolve to C♯ major. But sometimes we have the applied dominant come after the temporary tonic, too. (It's unclear to me where this G♯ moves; it might go back to C♯!)

As for another "exception," if you ever encounter a minor chord where you're not expecting it, it's often a result of mode mixture (some use the term "borrowed chords"). (See [How do I correctly borrow chords from one key to another?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/70607/how-do-i-correctly-borrow-chords-from-one-key-to-another/) for one possible discussion of mode mixture. You also might enjoy [What are the different ways of adding non-diatonic chords?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/57733/what-are-the-different-ways-of-adding-non-diatonic-chords))

**TL;DR:** That G♯ chord is understood as a temporary V/C♯. Since C♯ is itself V of F♯, we label this chord V/V.

Comment: If you've ever listened to the Foo Fighters, you've heard a major `II`-- Dave Grohl can't go five minutes w/o using one-- and I love it every time.

Comment: @AlexanderNied Hmm... What's an example song of theirs which illustrates this?

Comment: So, I actually struggled to find a place where it is *clear* it's what he's doing- frequently what might be a `II` is more aptly described as a `IV` in what would otherwise be a minor key but flirting in the relative major space. The two clearest examples I could find quickly were in the choruses of *Walking After You* on *Color and the Shape* and *Another Round* on *In Your Honor*. Note in neither place is it being used as an applied dominant, so the usage may be different from your song- in the former the `II` leads to the `IV` and in the latter to the `vi`.

Comment: I'll add that V-ii (C#-G#m) is forbidden in common practice period harmony and a rare chord progression in general from my experience. C#-G# actually makes more sense to me in an F# major context.

Comment: "It's unclear to me where this G♯ moves ... ." From my recollection (supported by the chord annotations I see online), it moves to D♯m and repeats the progression to A♯m and C♯, but this time resolves via C♯7 to F♯.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to use the comments for this.  But what a clear, exhaustive answer.

Comment: @ScottWallace Better than exhausting! :-)

Answer (score 2):

You've fallen into the common trap of seeing a scale, and the triads that can be formed from it, as a restriction.

Yes, there is a set of chords that can be constructed from the notes of a scale. But that's no more than a mildly interesting fact. A song in a given key will use some of the diatonic chords a lot, others not so often. And other, non-diatonic chords will also very likely appear. The diatonic, scale-derived chords are not a restriction, not the chords that you MAY use. They're just the diatonic chords.

For instance, consider the C major key. C, Dm, F, G, Am will probably be used a lot. But D7, C#dim, Bb, Fm are more likely to be used than the (diatonic) B dim. And, if you're playing blues-based styles, C7, F7 and G7 are the basic chords, two of which are non-diatonic!

THE SCALE IS A FRAMEWORK, NOT A RESTRICTION.

Once you absorb this, a lot of the 'borrowing' thing becomes unnecessary.   Where a chromatic chord IS used as a gateway to a modulation, there's sense in calling it borrowed.    An Fm chord in C major MIGHT be a pre-echo of a Fm7, Bb7, Eb modulation to Eb.  So calling it 'borrowed from Eb major' is useful.   But C C7, F, Fm, G7, C at the end of 'When the Saints' doesn't go anywhere.  Just let C7 and Fm be chromatic chords.  'Borrowing' them doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

The Ⅱ chord can serve mostly two roles:

- A secondary dominant, as said by Richard. This would be clearly the intepretation to go if the two last chords were turned around:

  ```
  ⅵ | ⅲ | Ⅴ/Ⅴ | Ⅴ
  ```

  I wouldn't interpret the G♯ as a secondary dominant here though, if it doesn't really depend on the Ⅴ chord.
- As a borrowed chord from the [Lydian mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydian_mode). The F♯-Lydian scale is F♯-G♯-A♯-B♯-C♯-D♯-E♯-. I does contain all the third line as diatonic chords. Or you might say that this entire section modulates to d♯-[Dorian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorian_mode).